How to get aggregated results that found inside WHERE id IN fields?
I need to get list of transactions with list of logs and tags inside each transaction and the most important make search by field in logs and tags and unite it all.
Example below is search by field1 and tag1. How to do that? Also important: I have 500m+ rows. If using WHERE id IN .. will it be slow?
transactions
 id int
 hash var

id | hash 
------------
1  |  h1
2  |  h2
3  |  h3

logs
 transaction_id int
 field1 var
 value var

transaction_id | field1 | value 
-------------------------------
1              | f1     | v1
1              | f2     | v2
2              | f3     | v3
3              | f4     | v4

tags
 transaction_id int
 tag1 var
 value var

transaction_id | tag1   | value 
-------------------------------
1              | t1     | v1
2              | t2     | v2
2              | t3     | v3

I need result:
id | hash | logs_array                                                         | tags_array
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | h1   | [{'field1': 'f1', 'value': 'v1'}, {'field1': 'f2', 'value': 'v2'}] | [{'tag1': 't1', 'value': 'v1'}]
2  | h2   | [{'field1': 'f3', 'value': 'v3'}]                                  | [{'tag1': 't2', 'value': 'v2'}, {'tag1': 't3', 'value': 'v3'}]
3  | h3   | [{'field1': 'f4', 'value': 'v4'}]                                  | []

Example template I can think of:
SELECT t.id, t.hash, array_agg(..) FROM transactions t WHERE id in
    (
        SELECT transaction_id FROM logs WHERE field1={any_string}
    )
    OR id in
    (
        SELECT transaction_id FROM tags WHERE tag1={any_string}
    )
LEFT JOIN logs lo ON t.id = lo.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN tags ta ON t.id = ta.transaction_id


Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what you’re asking. You appear to have written some SQL so does it give the result you want or not? If not, what is the issue? If it works then what’s stopping you running it to see if it’s slow or not?

Pre-aggregate the joins.

@NickW template example in my question is the only one I could think of, but it does not work as expected, because there needs somehow to aggregate results, I don't know how. Also I am not sure if condition WHERE id IN .. is fast execution
@Charlieface yeah, I don't know how

That could be accomplished with a query like this
select t.id, t.hash, 
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('field1', l.field1, 'value', l."value"))) logs_array,
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('tag1', tg.tag1, 'value', tg."value"))) tags_array
from transactions t 
left join logs l on t.id = l.transaction_id 
left join tags tg on t.id = tg.transaction_id
group by t.id, t.hash 
order by t.id;

Another version using conditions and stripping nulls
select t.id, t.hash, 
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('field1', l.field1, 'value', l."value"))) logs_array,
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('tag1', tg.tag1, 'value', tg."value"))) tags_array
from transactions t 
left join logs l on t.id = l.transaction_id 
left join tags tg on t.id = tg.transaction_id
where l.field1 = 'f1' and tg.tag1 = 't1'
group by t.id, t.hash
order by t.id;

another version optimized for performance
with cte as 
 (  select transaction_id id, 
    array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('tag1', tag1, 'value', value))) res_array
    from tags 
    where tag1 = 't1' 
    group by transaction_id
    union all
    select transaction_id id, 
    array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('field1', field1, 'value', value))) res_array
    from logs 
    where field1 = 'f1'
    group by transaction_id 
 )
select t.id, t.hash, array_agg(res_array) res_array from transactions t
right join cte c on t.id = c.id
group by t.id, t.hash;

Fiddle to test 

Thank you for answer. But where is where condition? In my case field1={any_string} and tag1={any_string}? This is marked as important in my question

@sirjay adding conditions is trivial, but added an example, also removing nulls

Works, thank you. Lastly, can you suggest what index to create? Because with millions of rows it took 90 seconds to execute. Will it be
CREATE INDEX idx_tr_id ON "transactions" (id); CREATE INDEX idx_lo_field1 ON "logs" (field1, transactiond_id); CREATE INDEX idx_ta_tags ON "tags" (tag1, transaction_id);?

I recommend independent indexes for primary keys and compound indexes for columns involved in frequent where conditions, but there are another factors that modify query performance. The best approach is analyzing execution plans, check this blog to know how to tune performance. https://use-the-index-luke.com/

@sirjay added a new version of the query optimized for performance, using the indexes that you mention.

I think it's preferable to do a pre-aggregation.
Pre-selecting and grouping significantly (by orders of magnitude) reduce the number of rows to be selected in all tables.
See example
SELECT t.id, t.hash, logs_array, tags_array
FROM 
(select transaction_id,array_agg(el1) tags_array 
  from
  (select transaction_id,JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(tag1,value) el1 FROM tags
    WHERE transaction_id in (
          SELECT transaction_id FROM tags WHERE tag1='t5' --{any_string}
      )
  )st
  group by transaction_id
)ta 
full join
(select transaction_id,array_agg(el1) logs_array 
  from
  (select transaction_id,JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(field1,value) el1 FROM logs
    WHERE transaction_id in (
          SELECT transaction_id FROM logs WHERE field1='f4' --{any_string}
      )
  )sl
  group by transaction_id
)la on la.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id
left join transactions t on t.id=coalesce(la.transaction_id,ta.transaction_id)

Demo
Joins performance - there is no doubt about it. Surely there are suitable indexes.
The main cost of the operation will be in the search for WHERE field1={any string} (also WHERE tag1={any_string}), "full table scan"  if no suitable indexes.

Perfect works on logs table, but I don't know why on tags return wrong on my database, although I see on dbfiddle demo works correct. Can I get you telegram to ask details (you can send me telegram to my email on stackoverflow profile)? I will pay you some $ for help
